# Evalute $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin 4x}{1 + x^4} dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

The problem is to evalute 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin 4x}{1 + x^4} dx.
$$
It may be too long to write all the details of the solution here. It will probably suffice for me to know what kind of contour I need to use and whether other integral values used in the attempt can be controlled.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on your contour? If you take the contour $[-R;R]\cup \{\Im z>0,\,|z|=R\}$, then, because of $\sin$ being odd, you can't deduce anything on the desired integral.

Comment: This isn't going to work the way you're doing it.  First, the contour you're describing doesn't tell you anything about the integral you want.  It tells you about $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$, which is obviously zero by symmetry.  Second, since nothing's going on at the origin, the limit of the latter integral isn't interesting either; it's just $0$.

Comment: Ye guys the indented integral didn't work; I'm kind of revising the whole thing  and I think I need to approach by a different method.

Answer (score 1):

Instead consider

$$\int_{C} \dfrac{e^{4iz}}{1+z^{4}}\tag{*}$$ Where $C$ is the upper half semi circle of radius large enough to contain all the pole.

Then we have

$$\int_{C} \dfrac{e^{4iz}}{1+z^{4}}dz=\int_{C}\dfrac{\cos{4z}}{1+z^{4}}dz+i\int_{C}\dfrac{\sin{4z}}{1+z^{4}}dz.$$

So to compute your integral compute $(*)$ and take the imaginary part. Note for the computation of $(*)$ we are only interested in the poles that lie in the upper half of the plane. Then divide by $2$ since we have $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how to calculate $(*)$? I mean how to calculate the integral of that function on the negative real axis.